# Regex to match numbers with 0 or 1 occurrence of "." char in between

Tags: java, regex

Trying to find out a regex to match exactly 4 numbers with 0 or 1 occurrence of  "."  char in between and 0 or 2 digits after the "." character

Acceptable match - `1234`, `2341.2`, `2133.12`

I tried this - `\d{3,}\.??[0-9]{1,2}`

But this is also matching -  the following inputs `171034`, `13234535`

If i give `\d{3}\.??[0-9]{1,2}` - It doesnt match `2341.2` or `2133.12`

Any suggestions what am i doing wrong

Comment: One way to do this is to expressly match the number of characters you need.  "\d{3,}" will match any amount of number characters more than 2, so it's not going to help.  "\d\d\d\d" will match four characters, "\d\d\d\.\d" will match three characters followed by a . and another digit. "\d\d\d\d|d\d\d\.\d" will match either.  Just keep going like that.

Comment: Not sure what you need. Try [`\b\d{4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/7qnSu8/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex**: `^\d{4}\.\d{1,2}$|^\d{4}$` or `^\d{4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

**Output**:

```
3333       true
3133.3     true
3133.33    true
3221.232   false
12344.33   false
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cbRhdy/2)

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped and exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Try this one out for size:

```
\d{4}(\.\d{0,2})?
```

Go ahead and test it on https://regexr.com/ :)

Comment: Thank you very much